# How to release Android app update without existing keystore file?

Tags: android, android-keystore, android-signing

The developer that managed our Android app was recently released, and I have since been tasked with publishing an update to the Play Store.

1. Can I release an update with a newly generated keystore file?
2. We have his laptop - where can I locate the existing keystore file?
3. Are there any steps I can take if we can't determine the password used for the existing keystore file?

Comment: "Can I release an update with a newly generated keystore file? " -- no. "We have his laptop - where can I locate the existing keystore file?" -- we have no way to know. However, you might check your Gradle scripts for signing information, as that may give you some clues for where to look. "Are there any steps I can take if we can't determine the password used for the existing keystore file?" -- resolve to make sure that you have your signing keystore for the next app that you build.

Comment: If the developer used upload key and let Google Play to sign your up with app key, than [you can reset](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#reset_upload_key) the upload key.

Comment: @esentsov Is there a way I can check if upload key was used either from Play Console or another method?

Comment: You can check it in Google Play Console / Select your app / Release management / App signing. Check there if app signing by google is enabled.